# Looping through one column and populating another concurrently

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through one column and update cells in another column, in a separate sheet (Export), based on values in the first column. Whenever I run this code, it just seems to updated the first cell in the second column with the last value from the first.

This is the code I have been trying to use:

```
Sub Update()
Dim cell As Range, rw As Long
rw = 2
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("J14:J33")
   If cell.Value = "xx" Then
   Worksheets("Export").Cells(rw, 14).Value = "xx"
   ElseIf cell.Value = "xxx" Then
   Worksheets("Export").Cells(rw, 14).Value = "xxx"
   ElseIf cell.Value = "xxxx" Then
   Worksheets("Export").Cells(rw, 14).Value = "xxxx"
   ElseIf cell.Value = "xxxxx" Then
   Worksheets("Export").Cells(rw, 14).Value = "xxxxx"
   ElseIf cell.Value = "xxxxxx" Then
   Worksheets("Export").Cells(rw, 14).Value = "xxxxxx"
   rw = rw + 1
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I am fairly new to VBA.

Comment: Your rw=rw+1 most likely should occur after the end if because at the moment it is only being actioned if cell.value = "xxxxx"

Comment: Does the row updated in the Export sheet have to be the same as the row in the activesheet.

Comment: No, sorry, I've not given a great explanation. It needs to be a value based off of the value, but not the same. So, if one cell is 'X' the other needs to be 'Y', but for a number of different values. Also, the cells that need to be looped in the activesheet are from J13-J33, but the cells that need updating in Export are N2-N22.

Comment: What if the activesheet cell is not one of the x, xx, xxx, xxxxx etc ?

Comment: If the activesheet cell is not any one of those values, it will be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Sub MyUpdate()

   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, n As Long
   Dim dict, k As String
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   With dict
       .Add "x", "y"
       .Add "xx", "yy"
       .Add "xxx", "yyy"
       .Add "xxxx", "yyyy"
       .Add "xxxxx", "yyyyy"
   End With
   
   With ThisWorkbook
      Set ws1 = .ActiveSheet '.Sheets("Sheet1")
      Set ws2 = .Sheets("Export")
   End With
   
   For n = 0 To 20
        k = Trim(ws1.Cells(n + 13, "J"))
        If dict.exists(k) Then
            ws2.Cells(n + 2, "N") = dict(k)
        Else
            'ws2.Cells(n + 2, "N") = "No match with " & k
        End If
   Next
   
   MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```